# talend tsystem multiline commands

Tags: amazon-s3, talend

I have command to move files between s3 folders. I am getting bucket name from context variable.
placed the command in array line

"aws s3 mv s3://"+context.bucket+"/Egress/test1/abc/xyz.dat s3://"+context.bucket+"/Egress/test1/abc/archive/archive_xyz.dat"

The command fetches the bucket name from context variable, but shows no file or direcrtory error=2. 
I think it is due to (") at begin and end.
Is there any way to solve.

please help

Comment: see array command: https://community.talend.com/t5/Design-and-Development/Executing-a-Linux-command-with-a-pipe-using-a-tSystem-component/ta-p/21671#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to use an array command.
Using /bin/bash or cmd

then your command.

[image]

Comment: It is working. But i want to check for file exists and then archive and place the new file

Comment: It is working. But i want to check for file exists and then archive and place the new file...how can i modify below command to array line, canu please help
"exists=$(aws s3 ls s3://"+context.bucket+"/path1/vr/vr1.txt) && if [ -z $exists ]; then echo aws s3 mv s3://"+context.bucket+"/publish/ACXIOM/axciom.dat s3://"+context.bucket+"/publish/ACXIOM/archive/axciom1.dat fi"